# Websphere application custom property

Tags: java, websphere

In Websphere (8.5) a custom property is definded under application. How to get that in Java.

Applications -> Application Types -> WebSphere enterprise applications -> "Application Name" -> Custom Properties

I tried `System.getenv(<<var>>)` and `System.getProperty(<<var>>)` nothing worked.

Comment: Are you really trying to read an application-specific property?  Or would a JVM-level property suit your needs?

Comment: application specific, as my value for a key changes based on application. I cannot keep at JVM level

Comment: Another question asking the same thing, no real answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229079/defining-custom-properties-in-application-panel-how-to-get-the-value-in-the-co Did you try the WebSphere forum? http://ibm.biz/websphere-forum

Comment: You can put custom property into Resource Environment and pick it up via JNDI. More can be found on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0611_totapally/0611_totapally.html

Comment: @MagicWand I will give a try